# NTLM proxy Authentication in Android

Tags: android, proxy, httpclient, ntlm, apache-httpclient-4.x

i am trying to use Httppost operation by using NTLM proxy authentication. I have used JCIFSEngine. But still i am getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, connectionTimeout);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, connectionTimeout);
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);

httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register(AuthPolicy.NTLM, new NTLMSchemeFactory());
    httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("proxyServerIP", 80, "http", "DOMAIN"),new NTCredentials("userNAme", "pass", null, "DOMAIN"));
```

I am getting this error:

```
<HEAD><TITLE>Proxy Authorization Required</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Proxy Authorization Required</H1><HR>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Authorization is required for access to this proxy<BR><BR>
</B>Error Code: <BR>(NTLM) NA c<BR><BR>
User Agent: <BR><BR><BR>
Error Detail: <BR><PRE>[2013/06/14 17:30:44.539735,  1] libsmb/ntlmssp.c:342(ntlmssp_update)
  got NTLMSSP command 3, expected 1
</PRE><BR><BR></B></FONT>
<HR>
<!-- default "Proxy Authorization Required" response (407) -->
</BODY>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to try Apache Software Foundation solution of the problem:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html#ntlm

4.9. NTLM Authentication

As of version 4.1 HttpClient provides full support for NTLMv1, NTLMv2, and NTLM2 Session authentication out of the box. One can still continue using an external NTLM engine such as JCIFS  library developed by the Samba project as a part of their Windows interoperability suite of programs.